# In the session monitor in the SQL text query is set up in a different way

Tags: sql, oracle, session, plsql, oracle-apex

help with query in oracle, in the session monitor in the sql text query is set up in a different way, for example I have the following query that is loaded in APEX in the After Header:

```
SELECT a.emp_descripcion, a.emp_id
  FROM cbe.employee a
 WHERE a.emp_status = 0
   AND a.rol_id  = 58  
   AND :f_ses_id IN (677,457,1124)
```

But, in the session monitor from PLSQL, in the SQL text it shows me that the query is built in a different way:

```
"select * from(select a.*,row_number() over (order by null) apx$rownum from(select i.*, count(*) over () as APEX$TOTAL_ROW_COUNT
 from (select *
from ((select /*+ qb_name(apex$inner) */* from (SELECT a.emp_descripcion, a.emp_id
  FROM cbe.employee a
 WHERE a.emp_status = 0
   AND a.rol_id  = 58  
   AND :f_ses_id IN (677,457,1124)
) d
 )) i 
) i where 1=1 
order by 1 asc nulls last
)a
)where apx$rownum<=:p$_max_rows"
```

Comment: that is normal. That is how APEX builds the queries internally. Your query goes exactly after the the `qb_name` hint for the `apex$inner` ( the one that finishes in d ). Is the expected behaviour

Comment: Looks like you've enabled pagination and are displaying the total number of records ("x-y of z"). The implementation of this means that the whole query needs to run to completion to get this count. If this isn't what you want (ie you don't care about the total count and the query needs to stop fetching when it reaches your page side), use the pagination options for your field in APEX.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I understand that internally APEX executes these querys in this way, however, we are in a process of migration of the APEX version and we saw that APEX is building the querys in this way, we are concerned about the "ORDER BY NULL" that is It is there because it could be the cause of the performance problems that we are currently having, perhaps it is losing some reference to execute that "ORDER BY NULL". Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: The clause `order by 1 nulls last` is *not* ordering by null. It is ordering by the 1st column of those returned and if that column contains null specifying they go to the end of the result set.  If you are migrating off Apex do not look at how Apex rewrites the query, it is specifically tailored to the internals of Apex. Whatever you are moving to will not be so tailored. Just look at the initial query.